# Number field without comma

Tags: formula-field

I have custom formula field with return type as number.So it is returning values with comma.Year__c is custom picklist field with values such as (2010,2011,2012,2013..).The reason behind (new formula field) converting the picklist value to number is to sort the records based on picklist values in report and  visualforce..So I created new formula field  with return type as number.

VALUE(TEXT(Year__c))

someone help me in removing the commas

Comment: Why can't you just sort on the formula field and display Year__c?

Comment: Thanks @PhilR It worked on visualforce page.What about the report

Answer (score 2):

Currently this is not possible. You can have the type be of text though `TEXT(Year__c)` if that will sort as you want it to given your data set

Comment: It won't sort correctly if I do text(year__c)

Comment: Then unfortunately you are out of luck at this time if you are showing the field. If you are not showing the field you can still sort on it in Visualforce and display the text field. I believe this has been a requested feature for several years now and like the ability to add approval comments to emails it has gone unanswered

Comment: is this still feature (ability to skip commas) in a number field resolved ? Or is there any workaround to achieve this ? I still find commas when I'm trying to save the number fields. I have tried a couple of methods found online but still have no luck!! @Eric